# MongoDB Regex $and $or Search Query

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to construct a query that will accept multiple fields that can be searched over using regex for partial field matching that also has a hard constraint on other fields.

Example:

Collection: "Projects" 
Required Information: { propertyId: "abc", clientId: "xyz" } 
Fields to be Searched: `name`, `serviceType.name`, `manager.name`

Currently, I have a query like this, but if there are no results it returns all the results, which isn't helpful.

```
{ 
 '$and': [ 
    { propertyId: '7sHGCHT4ns6z9j6BC' },
    { clientId: 'xyz' },
    { '$or': 
     [
       { name: /HVAC/gi },
       { 'serviceType.name': /HVAC/gi },
       { 'manager.name': /HVAC/gi }
     ] 
    } 
 ] 
}
```

If anyone has any insight into this it would be much appreciated.

Example Document:

```
{
  _id: "abc",
  propertyId: "7sHGCHT4ns6z9j6BC",
  clientId: "xyz"
  name: "16.000.001",
  serviceType: {
    _id: "asdf",
    name: "HVAC"
  },
  manager: {
    _id: "dfgh",
    name: "Patrick Lewis",
  }
}
```

The expected result is to only find documents `where` `propertyId` `=` `7sHGCHT4ns6z9j6BC` `AND` one at least one of the following keys: `name, serviceType.name, or manager.name` match an inputted string, in this case, it's `HVAC` and if none of the regex fields match, then return nothing.

**UPDATE**
The issue was with MongoDB, after restarting it, everything worked.

Comment: Please post sample documents for better solution

Comment: @Saleem i just updated the question with more insight and details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following script:

```
db.collection.find({
$and:[
  {propertyId:"7sHGCHT4ns6z9j6BC"}, 
  {
    $or:[
       {name: /HVAC/i}, 
       {"serviceType.name": /HVAC/i}, 
       {"manager.name": /HVAC/i}
    ]
  }]
})
```

Query above will return a document or documents if and only if `propertyId` matches and either of `name`, `serviceType.name` or `manager.name` matches desired regex.

Comment: Isn't this what I have, just minus the `clientId` and `greedy(g)`?

Comment: well, you are the judge :) usually mistakes are very small but hard to discover.

Comment: Yeh, its the same this is what my query is now. 
    { '$and': [ { propertyId: '7sHGCHT4ns6z9j6BC' }, { '$or': [
      { name: /asasdf/gi },
      { 'serviceType.name': /asasdf/gi },
      { 'manager.name': /asasdf/gi }
    ] } ] }

side note, after restarting MongoDB it randomly started working. Thank you @saleem for your time!